# including conditional statements in expect

Tags: bash, ssh, expect

I am trying to write a bash script that uses expect to scp a file to remote systems. The expect block that I have so far looks like this

```
expect -c "
    set timeout -1
    spawn scp $file user@host:$file
    expect "\Are you sure you want to continue connection (yes/no)\"
    send -- \"$password\r\"
    expect eof
    "
```

The problem is that this handles the case in which the host is not a known host and it asks if I want to continue connecting. I would like to add a an option for the case in which the host is already known and it simply wants the password.

The other issue is that I would like to handle the event in which the password the user entered is not correct. In that case, I would like to have the user reenter the password.

What would be the best way of accomplishing this using bash and expect?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: don't you want to respond `yes` if you are prompted `...(yes/no)` ?  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> host is not a known host and it asks if I want to continue connecting

Use: `scp -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" <...>`

> event in which the password the user entered is not correct

If your script is considered to be interactive, why you are using `expect` at all? `scp` can ask and re-ask a password by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
expect -c "
    set timeout -1
    spawn scp $file user@host:$file
    expect 
        {Are you sure you want to continue connection (yes/no)} {
            send \"yes\r\"
            exp_continue
        }
        {Password: } {
            send -- \"$password\r\"
        }
    }
    expect eof
"
```

The `exp_continue` command loops back to the containing expect command so that other patterns have a change to be matched.